# When uploading code onto a microprocessor, do comments matter at all?

Tags: c, comments

I was taught in my introduction to C class that comments were ignored.  So I didn't really care if I wrote a lot of comments.  However, now I am at that step where I would have to upload code into a microprocessor.  I'm assuming comments are still comments.. but all code takes up space.  Does this matter significantly in regards to memory of the microprocessor?  Am I assuming that because comments are ignored, that means that the microprocessor won't spend any cycles looking at it?  Or should I typically have the only necessary amount?  This might be a stupid question, but I don't know the answer off the top of my head.. :X  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I don't see why one could not add the comments - as debug info of sorts. :-)

Comment: All *machine* code takes up space. But not all high-level-language code produces machine code. Comments never do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're uploading the raw C code (which I don't think you're doing), then yes, the comments would take up space because the raw C code file would be bigger.  However, if you're uploading the compiled code (which I do think you're doing), it shouldn't make a difference.  During compilation the compiler should strip out all of the comments, and the code shouldn't be any bigger with comments than without.

That said, someone could build an evil compiler that did use more space for code with lots of comments in it, but no one actually does this; it would be impossible to market. :-)

Comment: This evil compiler can really help reverse engineering.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are not compiled into machine code, no.  They are for human eyes only.

Comment: It'd be pretty dumb of the compiler to do that.

Comment: It would be very, very dumb, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are uploading *complied* code to the processor:  no, comments do not take up space.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever looked at assembly, you'll see commands like this:

```
move mud, water
add mud, mud, water
; mud is really watery.
```

The `; ???` is a comment. It's always removed before the code is compiled to machine code.

Similarly, in machine code, your variable names don't get preserved. So, for example, `garbage` may turn into `0FA5291B039C190E89542` (which cannot in any way represent `garbage`, except for the fact that they're both garbage... get it?).

This is one reason you can't get your original C code back from the compiled code, after you compile it. If this could happen, [reverse engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) would be a lost art. (Yes, it's an art! The music of code! Appreciate the beauty!)